# Padding for Mobile Web in Appcelerator?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I'm working on an Appcelerator app. We're all new to the platform. For some reason, padding (left or right) - plus some other attributes - doesn't work for mobile web. In fact, I think it's only supported for iOS. What are we supposed to do instead? I've tried just using the CSS equivalent (e.g. padding-left: '10px') in the TSS file to no avail.

There's a bug report for it - https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-7304 - but it's almost two years old and still no traction on the matter.

Comment: For which UI control?

Comment: TextField, specifically

Answer (score 1):

You could use a View as a container, then use top/bottom/left/right in the inner element to achieve a padding-like effect. You can see an example of that here: https://gist.github.com/asiviero/7323029, it works on Android but I haven't tested on Mobile Web

Comment: This was my first thought for Android. But apparently, it looked good in Android without it. For mobile web, I used a webview and put an HTML page in it that was easy to style. Really lame. It seems like Appcelerator is an iOS-first platform with some Android support and a tiny smidgen of mobile web support. It's like you're making an iOS app with JavaScript instead of Objective-C :/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `padding-left` you should define `paddingLeft: '10px'`.

Comment: That doesn't work for mobile web. It only works for iOS. Please re-read the question